# What is the correct 3-legged OAuth workflow in Python (Example: ImmoScout API) ? (How to get request_token)

Tags: python, api, rest, oauth

I am trying to access the ImmoScout24 web api for a data science project in python and I kind of stuck in the 3 legged authentication process. I googled the problem but its kind of special, so maybe someone can help me.

I want to implement the workflow described on: https://api.immobilienscout24.de/api-docs/authentication/three-legged/#callback-url

To obtain the request_token (first step within the authentication process) I tried the following approach:

API Credentials are stored in those two variables:

`client_key`

`client_secret`

The Python code looks like follows

```
immoscout_api = OAuth1Session(client_key,
                            client_secret=client_secret)  

request_token_url='http://rest.immobilienscout24.de/restapi/security/oauth/request_token'

fetch_response = immoscout_api.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
```

I am getting an Error in my Jupyter Notebook that looks like the following:

```
TokenRequestDenied: Token request failed with code 403, response was '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Bad request.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: M_HHRf9VaNN9xFRqWlHWt2txfuIsBE5fe6siJACFUFjVWw20p91jLg==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>'.
```

Can somebody help me to obtain the request toke?